# Lambda function for sort(key=...) in Python

Tags: python, sorting, lambda, key

I have the following dictionary:

```
employees = [

    {'Name': 'Alan Turing', 'age': 25, 'salary': 10000},

    {'Name': 'Sharon Lin', 'age': 30, 'salary': 8000},

    {'Name': 'John Hopkins', 'age': 18, 'salary': 1000},

    {'Name': 'Mikhail Tal', 'age': 40, 'salary': 15000},

]
```

I now want to sort this dictionary with the key 'age' using Lambda. You can find below how I tried to figure this out:

```
print(list(map(employees.sort(key = lambda x: x.get('age')), employees)))
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 10, in <module>

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

How should I configure the lambda to get the correct output?

Thank you!

Comment: [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) returns `None` to "remind users it operates by side effect". Just use `employees.sort(key = lambda x: x.get('age'))  print(employees)`

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `sorted` instead of `sort`. The former returns a new array while the latter does the sorting in place.

```
print(list(sorted(employees, key = lambda x: x.get('age'))))
```

If you do want to sort in place, your version of `employees.sort(key=lambda x: x.get('age'))` works correctly. The call to sort doesn't return anything though, so if you want to verify the result, add another call to print

```
employees.sort(key=lambda x: x.get('age'))
print(employees)
```

Comment: Thank you, but what is wrong with using map and sort() instead of sorted, more or less both look very similar?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using sort. You cannot use map() and sort() together like this though. The call to sort() returns `None` which would be the input to map, that does not work.